# laravel form collective select option for edit selected

Tags: laravel

I want to populate the whole Edit form, but SelectBox does not grab the value and always stays on the first one.

```xml
<select id="groupId" name="groupId" class="form-control">
  @foreach(\Modules\Slider\Entities\SliderGroup::pluck('id', 'title') as $value => $id)
    <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ \Modules\Slider\Entities\Slider::pluck('groupId') === old('groupId', $id) ? 'selected' : ''  }}>{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is related to the way you're testing for equality:

```html
{{ \Modules\Slider\Entities\Slider::pluck('groupId') === old('groupId', $id) ? 'selected' : ''  }}
```

Strict equality checks both the value and type meaning that whilst `1` and `'1'` have the same value a `===` will fail as they are not the same type.

Rather than using `strict` equality, use `lenient` equality:

```html
{{ \Modules\Slider\Entities\Slider::pluck('groupId') == old('groupId', $id) ? 'selected' : ''  }}
```

Lenient equality checks just the value and ignores the type.